# how to use other, previous, values to create a new value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my first post having found so much of what I have needed previously by searching this site. I can't find an answer to this one, so here we go...I have a table containing the number of customers for around 40 organisations listed by month, sample as follows:

```
Month   OrgID   Cust
201509  G85001  12731
201509  G85006  10638
201509  G85106  2501
201510  G85001  12577
201510  G85006  10550
201510  G85106  2533....
```

I've written a script to show the data with the month going across the top (thanks to this forum!), which now looks like this:

```
OrgID   201605  201606  201607   201608  201609
G85001  12650   12650   12597    12597   12597
G85006  11182   11182   11074    11074   11074
G85012  21323   21323   0        0       0
G85034  11956   11956   58648    58648   58648
G85094  15857   15857   0        0       0
G85095  8436    8436    0        0       0
G85106  2429    2429    2426     2426    2426
```

(edited to include code that generates this:

```
SELECT        
    CSU.GPWP.[Organisation Code] AS ORGID, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN monthkey = '201603' THEN Customers ELSE 0 END) AS 201603, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN monthkey = '201604' THEN Customers ELSE 0 END) AS 201604, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN monthkey = '201605' THEN Customers ELSE 0 END) AS 201605, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN monthkey = '201606' THEN Customers ELSE 0 END) AS 201606, 
.....
FROM            CSU.GPWP 

GROUP BY CSU.GPWP.[Organisation Code]
```

You can see that G85012, G85094 and G85095 all go to 0 in the third column and G85034 increases, this is because the three branches are technically 'closed' and their customer list has been taken on by G85034. Unfortunately not all systems have been closed off and so I still need to report on each individual site. What I want to do is for the months with 0 customers, use the last complete month to estimate the customer size, based on the current total customers.

So, for June:

```
G85012  = 21323 (37%)
G85094  = 15857 (28%)
G85095  = 8436 (15%)
G85034  = 11956 (21%)
Total =  57572
```

And I want July as follows:
Total 58648 (G85034 total)

```
G85012  = 37%*58648 = 21722
G85094  = 28%*58648 = 16153
G85095  = 15%*58648 = 8594
G85034(new) = 21%*58648 = 12179
```

For all other sites I want to keep their existing customer list size. Is it possible to get SQL to calculate this on an ongoing basis? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, can you please post the script you are using to pivot the data into the monthly columns?

Comment: edited to add this

Comment: You have to have a record or attribute somewhere that indicates that G85034 is new in July. Then if I understand correctly, in July you want to spread values in all 'new' branches across the new branch and any closed branches based on the proportion in the prior month. So really we need another table that tells us when a branch is 'new' or taking up old customers, and preferrably when a branch is closed (it might be open and legitimately have 0 customers)

Comment: G85034 isn't 'new' in July, it exists before that with it's own customers and inherits the others from July. I haven't got a table with the closed dates because they still are technically open...:-/ The rest of your understanding is correct.

I can create a mapping table that would show which OrgIDs would be subsumed, which would show the same code in both fields for those that haven't changed, something like this:

`OrgID     NewOrdID
G85001  G85001
G85006  G85006
G85012  G85034
G85034  G85034
G85094  G85034
G85095  G85034
G85106  G85106`

would this be useful in solving it?

Answer (score 0):

The condition that CUST = 0 is not enough as soon as you need to correct the union record `G85034` where CUST <> 0

Say we have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE GPWP 
    ([Month] int, [OrgID] varchar(6), [Cust] int)
;

INSERT INTO GPWP 
    ([Month], [OrgID], [Cust])
VALUES
    (201605, 'G85001', '12650'),
    (201605, 'G85006', '11182'),
    (201605, 'G85012', '21323'),
    (201605, 'G85034', '11956'),
    (201605, 'G85094', '15857'),
    (201605, 'G85095', '8436'),
    (201605, 'G85106', '2429'),                

    (201606, 'G85001', '12650'),
    (201606, 'G85006', '11182'),
    (201606, 'G85012', '21323'),
    (201606, 'G85034', '11956'),
    (201606, 'G85094', '15857'),
    (201606, 'G85095', '8436'),
    (201606, 'G85106', '2429'),     

    (201607, 'G85001', '12597'),
    (201607, 'G85006', '11074'),
    (201607, 'G85012', '0'),
    (201607, 'G85034', '58648'),
    (201607, 'G85094', '0'),
    (201607, 'G85095', '0'),
    (201607, 'G85106', '2429'),   

    (201608, 'G85001', '12597'),
    (201608, 'G85006', '11074'),
    (201608, 'G85012', '0'),
    (201608, 'G85034', '58648'),
    (201608, 'G85094', '0'),
    (201608, 'G85095', '0'),
    (201608, 'G85106', '2429'),   

    (201609, 'G85001', '12597'),
    (201609, 'G85006', '11074'),
    (201609, 'G85012', '0'),
    (201609, 'G85034', '58648'),
    (201609, 'G85094', '0'),
    (201609, 'G85095', '0'),
    (201609, 'G85106', '2429')
    ;
```

We need to know which records got united and also a share of each record in the united record. So you should create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE GPWP_UNIONS
    ([StartMonth] int,[EndMonth] int, 
     [OrgID] varchar(6), [ParentOrgID] varchar(6), 
     [Share] money);
;

INSERT INTO GPWP_UNIONS
    ([StartMonth],[EndMonth], [OrgID], [ParentOrgID], [Share])
VALUES
    (201607,201609, 'G85012', 'G85034',0.37),
    (201607,201609, 'G85094', 'G85034',0.28),
    (201607,201609, 'G85095', 'G85034',0.15),
    (201607,201609, 'G85034', 'G85034',0.21);
```

Here `StartMonth` is the month of the union. `EndMonth` the final month if you need to get back and cancel union in this month (You can use `999999` if you need an endless union). `ParentId` is OrgId of the union record. `Share` is a percent/100 of each record in the total sum.

Using the following query we get desired result:

```
WITH GPWP_WITH_UNIONS AS
(
  SELECT GPWP.OrgID,
         GPWP.month,
         ISNULL(GPWP_PARENT.Cust*GPWP_UNIONS.Share,GPWP.Cust) as Cust

  FROM GPWP
  -- Get a Share If it is an UNION record
  LEFT JOIN GPWP_UNIONS ON (GPWP.OrgID = GPWP_UNIONS.OrgID)
                       AND 
                      (GPWP.month BETWEEN GPWP_UNIONS.StartMonth 
                                      AND GPWP_UNIONS.EndMonth) 
  -- get the Parent CUST value if it is an UNION record
  LEFT JOIN GPWP AS GPWP_PARENT ON (GPWP_UNIONS.ParentOrgID = GPWP_PARENT.OrgID)
                       AND 
                      (GPWP.month = GPWP_PARENT.month)                       

)
SELECT        
    OrgID AS ORGID, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = '201603' THEN Cust ELSE 0 END) AS [201603], 
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = '201604' THEN Cust ELSE 0 END) AS [201604], 
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = '201605' THEN Cust ELSE 0 END) AS [201605], 
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = '201606' THEN Cust ELSE 0 END) AS [201606],
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = '201607' THEN Cust ELSE 0 END) AS [201607],
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = '201608' THEN Cust ELSE 0 END) AS [201608],
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = '201609' THEN Cust ELSE 0 END) AS [201609]   
FROM  GPWP_WITH_UNIONS 

GROUP BY GPWP_WITH_UNIONS.ORGID;
```

Result:

```
╔════════╦════════╦════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ ORGID  ║ 201603 ║ 201604 ║  201605  ║  201606  ║  201607  ║  201608  ║  201609  ║
╠════════╬════════╬════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ G85001 ║ 0.00   ║ 0.00   ║ 12650.00 ║ 12650.00 ║ 12597.00 ║ 12597.00 ║ 12597.00 ║
║ G85006 ║ 0.00   ║ 0.00   ║ 11182.00 ║ 11182.00 ║ 11074.00 ║ 11074.00 ║ 11074.00 ║
║ G85012 ║ 0.00   ║ 0.00   ║ 21323.00 ║ 21323.00 ║ 21699.76 ║ 21699.76 ║ 21699.76 ║
║ G85034 ║ 0.00   ║ 0.00   ║ 11956.00 ║ 11956.00 ║ 12316.08 ║ 12316.08 ║ 12316.08 ║
║ G85094 ║ 0.00   ║ 0.00   ║ 15857.00 ║ 15857.00 ║ 16421.44 ║ 16421.44 ║ 16421.44 ║
║ G85095 ║ 0.00   ║ 0.00   ║ 8436.00  ║ 8436.00  ║ 8797.20  ║ 8797.20  ║ 8797.20  ║
║ G85106 ║ 0.00   ║ 0.00   ║ 2429.00  ║ 2429.00  ║ 2429.00  ║ 2429.00  ║ 2429.00  ║
╚════════╩════════╩════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```